# Django/Python Circular model reference

Tags: python, django, django-models

Ok So I'm TRYING to write nice organized code and actually making seperate django apps instead of lumping everything together into 1. My problem is that I have 3 apps that each reference 1 other model from the next app. So basically I have an endless loop, App A needs to know about B.models.something1   , App B needs to know about C.models.Somthing2, and App C needs to know about A.models.something3 . This of course will not run, for those wondering if this is actually a problem :) .Is there anything resembling a predeclaration of classes so python will know that the classes actually exist?

Thanks.

EDIT: More Code:
Unfortunatly the nature and models of my project are confidential so I'll have to change the names to reflect something completely different , but the code will remain the same.

teacher/models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 from myapp.student.models import *
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 class Teacher(models.Model):
     """(description)"""
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
     phone_ext = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=5)
     fax = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=13)
     fax_ext = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     url = models.URLField(blank=True, verify_exists=True)
     complaint = models.ManyToManyField(Complaint)
     city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     postal_code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
     location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
 class Location(models.Model):
     """(description)"""
     city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     country = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.city + ", " + self.state +", "+self.country
```

student/models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from myapp.school.models import School

 class Student(models.Model):
     """(Student description)"""
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     locale = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=5)
     learningtype = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     sites = models.TextField(blank=True)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.user)

 class Complaint(models.Model):
     """(Complaint description)"""
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
     site = models.ForeignKey(School)
     complaint = models.TextField(blank=False)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.site)
```

school/models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 from myapp.teacher.models import Location
 class School(models.Model):
     """(School description)"""
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     url = models.URLField(verify_exists=True)
     img = models.ImageField(upload_to="casion_img/")
     rating = models.FloatField()
     description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
     goodstanding = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

So here's what I'm getting:

File "/Users/userzero/django/myapp/school/models.py", line 2, in 
    from teacher.models import Location
  File "/Users/userzero/django/myapp/teacher/models.py", line 2, in 
    from student.models import Complaint
  File "/Users/userzero/django/myapp/student/models.py", line 3, in 
    from school.models import School
  File "/Users/userzero/django/myapp/casino/models.py", line 2, in 
    from teacher.models import Location
ImportError: cannot import name Location

Comment: Import cycles are not necessarily a problem. But without more code we can't figure out what it really is.

Answer (score 37):

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To refer to models defined in another
>   application, you can explicitly
>   specify a model with the full
>   application label. For example, if the
>   Manufacturer model above is defined in
>   another application called production,
>   you'd need to use:

```
class Car(models.Model):
     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('production.Manufacturer')
```

> This sort of reference can be useful
>   when resolving circular import
>   dependencies between two applications.

So for your apps, try changing e.g.

```
 location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

to

```
 location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
```

Note that if this model is in a different app then you need to specify that too (thanks @Bran for pointing this out), e.g.

```
 location = models.ForeignKey('teacher.Location')
```

Comment: I don't know PyCheckMate, but... if your Django apps work, and the fix is a documented Django technique, then my guess is the fault is in PyCheckMate

Comment: Turns out this dosen't work. Why syncb worked is apparently the apps got removed from my settings file somehow (Considering I didn't edit it and I'm the only one on the project I have no idea how that happened either).

Comment: That's a blow! From your description of the problem the model string thing should work. If it doesn't there must be something else going on. Can you try deleting everything from two of your three apps and adding it back bit by bit until an exception is thrown. Do your error messages give any other clues? I've had errors like yours when I was trying to register models with the admin site (admin was trying to validate the models before the models were ready to be validated).

Comment: you have to include the app name so instead of `models.ForeignKey('Location')` you would use `models.ForeignKey('teacher.Location')`