# Forward class declaration in Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I have two classes in order:

```
class A(models):
    ...

class B(models):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Now I have to change my model to one below:

```
class A(models):
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)

class B(models):
    ...
```

I have to use south migrations. I wanted to create new many to many field in class A, migrate data and delete field from class B. The problem is that both are in same model. So when I put many to many into A class it cannot be seen. Because B declaration is below A. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django models: mutual references between two classes and impossibility to use forward declaration in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298326/django-models-mutual-references-between-two-classes-and-impossibility-to-use-fo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least SQLAlchemy allows you to use a string instead of a class. Try if django-orm allows that, too.

```
a = models.ManyToManyField('A')
# ...
b = models.ManyToManyField('B')
```

Update: According to [Django/Python Circular model reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813293/django-python-circular-model-reference/4813461#4813461) that's exactly the way to go.

Comment: (As an aside, in SQLAlchemy using strings in place of classes works only with DeclarativeBase.  If you are using mapper directly, you cannot use that technique, but you don't need it either)