# Django models: mutual references between two classes and impossibility to use forward declaration in python

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, forward-declaration

I have defined two models where each one references the other, like so:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ...
    loves = models.ManyToManyField(Article, related_name='loved_by')

class Article(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

You see, the problem is both classes references each other. No matter in what order these two classes are implemented, python always raises `NameError` exception, complaining either one class is not defined.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can find the solution in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
>     # ...
>
> class Manufacturer(models.Model):
>     # ...
> ```