# Referencing a class in python before it is declared

Tags: python, django, forward-declaration

I am using direct examples from the Django REST framework tutorial, I have 2 classes: `UserSerializer` and `SnippetSerializer`. I want to be able to use `UserSerializer` as a serializer in the `SnippetSerializer` class declaration, but for reasons, `SnippetSerializer` needs to be declared first.

Code example:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    #unimportant stuff

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #unimportant stuff - lets say we reference SnippetSerializer here
```

The obvious answer that comes to mind is a forward declaration, but from all my research, I cannot find this in Python.

Another solution I thought might work, which didn't (perhaps I did it wrong?) is instead trying to declare this relationship in the init method

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.owner = UserSerializer()
        super(SnippetSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this seemed to be completely ignored by the framework.

I also tried using the `@addto`, but it seems it only works for functions, not attributes/properties

Is there a way around this problem? This chicken-before-egg class problem has been killing me in Python for a while, but I've finally run into an instance where it is actually stopping me from getting the job done.

Comment: Are you declaring classes after the program starts? Typically you would declare classes / functions before you run the program.

Comment: I know zilch about Django, but the classic approach would be a UserSerializerBase declared *before* SnippetSerializer, and then inheriting UserSerializer from that. And this being Python, you can of course change the actual class definition after the fact, thus declaring UserSerializer before SnippetSerializer, and then modifying it later.

Comment: @user - yes, but as django is an interpreted language without headers, and it doesn't do the forward-reading thing that languages like javascript do, you cant reference another class before the code has reached its declaration.

Comment: @deets - I see what you are saying, and that method KIND OF works, but not completely, due to Djangos nested class stuff not inheriting from each other. It's a good idea though I will keep in mind in the future. Also, curiosity, I'm recently new to actually interacting on this site. Why do people so often comment instead of giving an answer that can be properly upvoted/accepted?

Comment: Usually comments are for peoples guess work or sort of "have you tried this?". Answers are for 100% certainty this will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django models: mutual references between two classes and impossibility to use forward declaration in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298326/django-models-mutual-references-between-two-classes-and-impossibility-to-use-fo)

Comment: No. That appears to be a database library specific workaround, but not a workaround for the general language.

Comment: "_but for reasons, SnippetSerializer needs to be declared first._" What are those reasons? You should show some code due to which you need this. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to provide a string containing the (dot notation) path to the class, instead.

Using DRF, you may have a folder structure like so:

```
├── appname
│   ├── ...
│   └── serializers.py
├── ...
```

`SnippetSerializer` and `UserSerializer` declared inside the above `serializers.py` file.

You'd then reference `UserSerializer` using the string: `"appname.serializers.UserSerializer"` where you'd normally write `UserSerializer`

Answer (score -1):

According to me, we can create function and then add function call for creating serializer

```
def fun():
    return UserSerializer()

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = fun()
    #unimportant stuff

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    pass
```

Will this work for you ?

Comment: This was a problem from 6.5 years ago. I don't remember what the reason was for, nor do I still have access to the code that I needed this for, but if I said SnippetSerializer needed to be declared first, then that is part of the question, and could not be bypassed. I'm sure a lot has changed in the last 6+ years, with a possible solution being added into the language/framework. But at this point, there is no way for me to resurrect this and answer if your code is a solution or not.

Comment: @Dakusan Thankyou for your response. Currently I have tested in my django environement and this seems to be working. If you want you can also test the same so that others don't stuck on this in future.

Answer (score -2):

This question sounds very similar to other Django forward-declaration questions posted on StackOverflow. Could you use something like [this style of forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330235/8250133) You would need to wrap the `owner` member in a Django function call, and I don't know if there is an appropriate call to use in this case. This solution is also specific to Django, and not a native feature of Python.