# Django models definition ordering

Tags: python, django, models

For example, I have 2 models: **Model1** and **Model2**. **Model1** has field ForeignKey(**Model2**). Model2 has method, that returns all instances of **Model1** which has this instance of **Model2** as ForeignKey.

But it doesn't work, because **Model2** is defined after **Model1** and it knows nothing about **Model2**. How to solve this problem?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5308895/183066). What you need to do is use strings according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5309027/183066).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the django docs. You can specify the model using a string so it evaluates later: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model2 = models.ForeignKey('Model2')


class Model2(models.Model):
    """Another model"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that method that returns all instances of model1 that have that foreign key? You can use the related field manager from model2 to achieve that. Model2.field_in_model1_set.all() ?